# How can I fortify homemade soy milk?

Tags: food-science, vegetarian, vegan, soymilk, vitamins

Commercial soy milk is fortified with lots of different vitamins. Is it possible to add these vitamins to homemade soy milk? If so how would you do it?

I'm not sure if we absorb the vitamins or if they are important or whatever, but just curious about how this would be done in a home kitchen.

Edit:

Found some links, neither of which gives a great answer considering both only really cover calcium, and state its a matter of mixing in a powder and shaking before drinking to keep dissolved:

http://www.livestrong.com/article/362920-how-to-fortify-homemade-soy-milk/

http://www.makesoyamilk.com/soya-milk-benefits/should-you-fortify-your-soy-milk

But commercial soymilk can include a ton of others (A, C, D, E, K, B6, Iron, Riboflavin, Folate, Phosphorous, Magnesium, Zinc, Selenium...). Wondering if it's also just a matter of mixing in a powder (like ground up multivitamins) and keeping suspending by shaking or the edition of additives like emulsifiers.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be adding any ascorbic acid or such -would curdle the milk- but an oil based vitamin such as found inside a vitamin E gel-cap would mix in fine. Would only be as absorbable or bio-available as the original vitamin product.

The idea of fortifying soya comes from the notion that we get a large amount of our nutrients from cows milk and without it, must substitute. The answer in general as to 'how important' is to eat a wide variety of whole foods instead of relying on fortified foods.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious about how all those vitamins get added into the beverage and I haven't found many resources on the web about this. I realize that the idea may be flawed from the 'how important' standpoint, but that's why I was trying to clarify the question and make it clear that I'm not asking about how important it is. I know it's better to get vitamins from whole foods, not from pills, powders, fortified foods, etc.